# Javascript how do I force string.replace not to interpret my string as a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Supposed I have a string foo that may have regexp special characters (eg a file path).

I have a string x

```
x.replace(foo, 'bar');
```

But I don't want foo to be interpretted as a regexp, I just want it to replace the literal string foo with 'bar'.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `foo` is a string, then it wont be interpretted as a regexp, it will just replace the literal string foo with `'bar'`.

`"aaa /bbb/ ccc".replace("/bbb/", "eee")` returns `"aaa eee ccc"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *foo* to be taken as literal, then pass it as a literal string:

```
str = x.replace('foo', 'bar');
```

Or, e.g.:

```
var path = "/bin/cat";
path = path.replace("/bin", "/usr/local/bin");
```

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method takes as the first argument either a regex, or a literal string.